# Python: What's wrong with this Python Code(requests)?

Tags: python

```
import requests
# import sys
# sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
def get_book():
    #http://search.dangdang.com/?key=c%D3%EF%D1%D4&act=input
    url="http://search.dangdang.com/"

    rest=requests.get(url,parms={
        'key':'c%D3%EF%D1%D4',
        # "enc":"utf-8",
        # "wq":"haixian",
        'act':'input'
    })
    rest = requests.get(url)
    print(rest.text)
    # rest.json()
    # rest.content



    #requests.post()

if __name__=="__main__":
    get_book()
```

Process finished with exit code 1
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parms'
It cannot work. 
What's the problem with this code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/. it is params not parms.  Your code works for me after changing this. I suggest you remove this question since it is not relevant to others after you

Answer (score 1):

Use `params` instead of `parms`

```
import requests
# import sys
# sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
def get_book():
    #http://search.dangdang.com/?key=c%D3%EF%D1%D4&act=input
    url="http://search.dangdang.com/"

    rest=requests.get(url,params={
        'key':'c%D3%EF%D1%D4',
        # "enc":"utf-8",
        # "wq":"haixian",
        'act':'input'
    })
    rest = requests.get(url)
    print(rest.text)
    # rest.json()
    # rest.content



    #requests.post()

if __name__=="__main__":
    get_book()
```